# pagination not working from second page onwards

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

searching from 2 fields 'location' and 'resTitle' . Code working fine with proper pagination when searched with 'resTitle' but pagination tab disappears when being searched using 'location'.

controller---

```
    $search = ($this->input->get("resTitle"))? $this->input->get("resTitle") : "NIL";
    $search = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $search;  

    $searchLoc = ($this->input->get("location"))? $this->input->get("location") : "NIL";
    $searchLoc = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $searchLoc;

        if($this->input->get("resTitle")!= 'null'){

    $total_row_res=  $this->common_model->res_count($search,"") ;
    $limit = 3;        

    $config = array();
    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."res_search/index/$search";
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['first_url'] = '1';
    $config['total_rows'] =  $total_row_res;

   $data['result']=$search;
   $data['total_row_res'] = $total_row_res;      
   } 

   else{
    $total_row_loc=  $this->common_model->res_count("",$searchLoc) ;
    $limit = 3;        

    $config = array();
    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
    $config['base_url'] = base_url()."res_search/index/$searchLoc";
    $config['per_page'] = $limit;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
    $config['first_url'] = '1';
    $config['total_rows'] =  $total_row_loc;
   $data['resultLoc']=$searchLoc;
   $data['total_row_loc'] = $total_row_loc;
   }

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
    $config['first_link'] =  'First';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);     


   $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
   $data['offset'] = ($data['page'] == 0 ? 0 : ($data['page'] - 1) * $limit);

   $data['searchList'] = $this->common_model->search($this->table, $search, $searchLoc, $limit, $data['offset']);
   $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();        

   $data['start'] = ($data['page'] == 0 ? 1 : (($data['page']-1) * $limit + 1));    `
```

view---------

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<?php   
foreach ($searchList as $row){?>    
    <article class="search-result row">


        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet">
        <p><?= $start; ?></p>
            <p class="text-success"><?php echo $row->type_name; ?></p>
            <h3><a href="#" title=""><?php echo $row->res_name; ?></a></h3>

            <p ><?php echo $row->loc_name; ?></p>   
            <p > <?php echo $row->add_details;?>, <?php echo $row->loc_name; ?>, <?php echo $row->city_name; ?></p>     

            <p >CUISINES:   <?php echo $row->cuisine_name; ?></p>                       
            <p >COST FOR TWO:   ₹<?php echo $row->cost; ?></p>                      
            <p> <?php echo $row->contact; ?></p>                        
        </div>
        <span class="clearfix borda"></span>
    </article>      
<?php 
$start++; 
}  ?>

</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $pagination; ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: Is "c;`if(($thi" right?

Comment: that was just a uploading error on my part. I've edited that part.. can u suggest what else is causing the error?